# Nested CSS Grid w/ Single-File Vue Components

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, css-grid

Can anyone tell me how to properly implement [this example](http://gridbyexample.com/examples/example21/) where the parent grid is `App.vue` and the child grid is `Hello.vue` (using the convention of the standard Webpack template)?

I've tried the following but the child grid doesn't seem to work.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <div id="top"></div>
      <div id="bottom"><router-view></router-view></div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
 export default {
     name: 'app',

 }
</script>


<style>
#app {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
 }
 #top {
     background: blue;
 }
 #bottom {
     background: green;
 }
</style>
```

Hello.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">

        <div id="head"></div>
        <div id="tail"></div>
    </div>
</template>

 <script>
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>


<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style>
 .hello {
     display: subgrid;
     grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
 }
 #head {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
 #tail {
     grid-column: 1 / 2;
     grid-row: 1 / 2;
     background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
 }
</style>
```

Edit: I've tried both `grid` and `subgrid` for the child's display property, neither works.

Here's the router definition:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
      {
          path: '/',
          name: 'Hello',
          component: Hello
      }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Where is your router definition?

Comment: @Potray  my router def is at `'./router/index.js'` relative to App.vue.  I'm adding it to the question.

Comment: Aren't you missing the Javascript part of the .vue files?

Comment: @Potray
I just didn't include it because I didn't think it was relevant

Comment: It is! Perhaps it's a behaviour error.

Comment: @Potray
I added the scripts

Comment: Well, you aren't using the child component (Hello.vue) in the parent component (App.vue), so there you have the problem.